# How to pull values from a url and pass them in a text form field in my template page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms, frontend

I am working on a Django environment. I need to pull some values from an URL. For instance:

```
http://x.x.x.x/abc/abcde/?*val1=123456&var1=random
```

From the above URL I need to pull the values of `val1` and `var1` and put/pass these values to a textbox field in a form in my HTML template. Later on, I need to pass these values to a Django `views.py` function.

I had initially passed form values to views function using `forms.py`. I found that method to be better and easier than AJAX. However this time I need to first pull the URL values. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in view function

```
val1 = request.GET.get('val1')
val2 = request.GET.get('val2')
```

then pass it to your html template

```
render (request,'html.html',{'val1':val1,'val2':val2})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

`request.query_params` is a more correctly named synonym for `request.GET`

```
val1 = request.query_params['val1']
val2 = request.query_params['val2']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer